# Krull dimension of local quotient ring and that of the original ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

If $A/I$ is a d-dimensional local ring, and $I$ is generated by $h$ elements, can we have the conclusion that dim A $\leq h+d$ ?

I was actually reading Commutative ring theory by Matsumura. And my problem is on p.120 the proof of theorem 12.6, The inequality right before the last paragraph. I am not really sure the inequality came from the construction in the proof or just the statement I proposed.

Thanks for answering!

Comment: We have $\dim A \geq \dim A/I + \operatorname{ht} I$ and the reverse inequality is wrong in general. In particular you have no chance to get something like $\dim A \leq \dotsc$.

Comment: Yes, I know this inequality. But in my question, the $h$ on rhs is not the height of $I$, instead, it is the number of generator of $I$.

Comment: This does not help at all. There are certainly examples where $h=\operatorname{ht} I$.